# Is it possible to get 98% f1-score on a binary classification task or am I messing up the calculations?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model

I recently used BERT for sentence classification on two datasets `GAD` and `EU-ADR`. I trained the datasets on the train files splitting the train files into train and validation. Then I tested on the test files provided by these datasets. I'm getting up to 98% f1-score on the test datasets and I am not sure if this is possible or my calculations are incorrect as the paper that I am comparing with doesn't report nearly as good a f1-score.

Link to paper [BioBERT: a pre-trained biomedical language representation model for biomedical text mining](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.08746)

It is worth noting that I am not using BioBERT (their pretrained BERT model) for this task. I am simply using BERT-base-uncased. The links to the github notebooks are below. Any insight would be helpful and I am open to provide any information required. Moreover, I have run the model several times and I still get really high scores.

[BERT relation extraction on GAD and EU-ADR datasets](https://github.com/hushee69/biobert-relation-extraction)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: of course it is possible to get such a high f1 score - at least in theory. if the benchmark is much lower than what you are observing and a very similar model is applied (biobert and bert only differ in their used data for language modeling afaik), then maybe some of your training data leaked into validation? just outright without code it is impossible to tell what might be going on (note that there are also different ways to calculate F1 scores, be sure you use the right one for the benchmark).

Comment: I used sklearn.metrics for the F1 score..moreover, I have provided links to the github colab that shows the executed code..I understand it is difficult to tell if the model might be biased..what I am certain of is that the test data was untouched and it is where I am getting high F1 scores.